# Find the maximum number of a column in relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show the result of user as a **winner** when he got the highest votes. Here is my controller code

```
 $users = User::where('area',$id)->get();
 return view('results.edit',compact('users'));
```

An here is my blade code

```
 @foreach($users as $key => $user)
     <tr>
         <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
         <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
         <td>{{$user->party->name}}</td>
         <td><img src="{{url('images/',$user->symbol)}}" width="50px" height="50px"></td>
         <td>{{$user->party->symbol_name}}</td>
         <td>{{$user->candidate ? $user->candidate->votes : ''}}</td>
         <td>Winner</td> <!-- if this user has the highest votes -->
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: and if there is more than one with the same highest vote?

Comment: If you have just one winner, than you should know who is the winner before starting this `@foreach`

Comment: then the result should be like these draw between these two users

Comment: @Luuk and hows that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate before the highest vote, and the users that have those vote

```
@php 
    $max = $users->max('candidate.votes');
    $users_max_vote = $users->where('candidate.votes', $max);
@endphp
@foreach
    ...
    @if($user->candidate->votes == $max) 
        @if($users_max_vote->count()>1)
            Draw between 
            @foreach($users_max_vote as $u) 
               {{$u->name}} 
            @endforeach 
        @else
            Winner 
        @endif
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: yes your way is correct but can you tell me what will i do when i have the same highest votes for twice user

Comment: in this case there will be two "winner" printed, tell me what you think code should be and i'll change in order to makes it working as you want

Comment: i want to make the winner which user has the highest votes and if some users has the same highest votes then it will show draw between these two users. e.g. draw between user 1 and user